# Input sanitation

Tags: login, security, sanitization

I have a question regarding a wordpress site I have recently developed for a client. I have only until now developed a site for small clients that just require personal websites, however this client has asked me to redeveloped his site as the current one has alot of security issues. Anyway I have created the site and shown it to him and he has asked if I can 'apply input sanitation so special characters like @,&,-,+,% are not allowed' to the login field.

- My question therefore is does Wordpress require further development
  to stop SQL injections etc on login forms? And do I need to apply input sanitation to the login fields?
- It seems odd to not allow special characters when special characters are better for passwords so should I do this? Bare in mind that the site doesn't have public registration. It has a login feature for partners which the admin would create the login for.

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp-login.php should not require additional effort from you to secure. However, I don't think that's what you client is asking for.

> My question therefore is does Wordpress require further development to
> stop SQL injections etc on login forms? And do I need to apply input
> sanitation to the login fields?

To wp-login.php, no, you don't. Not for security reasons, anyway, but that's not what your client asked for. They just asked to make "@,&,-,+,% are not allowed", which sounds like a business logic decision, and not related to security.

> It seems odd to not allow special characters when special characters
> are better for passwords so should I do this? Bare in mind that the
> site doesn't have public registration. It has a login feature for
> partners which the admin would create the login for.

From what you've said, your client didn't mention the password field. They just mentioned the "login" field, which I would interpret as the username field.